# Работа с таблицами расположенными в Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, access

База данных расположена в MySql
Подчинённая таблица через ODBC подключена к Аксес
Две таблицы связаны по полю "idsub" 1:М.
Характеристики основной таблицы :
   - кол строк - 1,0 млн  (может  больше )
   - количество столбцов ~ 20 штук
Характеристики подчинённой таблицы:
   - кол строк - > 1,0 млн
   - количество столбцов ~ 20 штук
Если увеличить количество строк в подчинённой таблице - более 100 000, то при 
перемещении курсором по записям основной таблицы компьютер начинает тормозить.

**Вопрос.**
Что можно сделать чтобы не было торможения?
Приемлемо ли использование такие инструменты - MySql, Аксес для такой базы?
Какое программное обеспечение желательно применять в таких ситуациях?
Или как правильно организовать взаимодействие между таблицами?

Файл находится по [ссылке](http://transfiles.ru/1b4s0)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ты уверен, что компьютер тормозит, а не Access? Не плохо бы обозначить мощность ПК, на котором происходит торможение.

Comment: Какая роль Access? Ты его используешь как оболочку для отчетов, а все вытягиваешь из MySql?

Answer (score 3):

Я бы не стал стравливать между собой Access и MySql.

Access в первую очередь программа для работы с настольными Access базами, а я как понял, вы используете его, как средство администратирования MySql

Если вопрос стоит только в администратировании MySql, то я бы выбрал бы что-нибудь из [этого](https://habrahabr.ru/post/142385/).

**Использовать ли MySql для такого объема данных?**

Зависит от потребностей.

Если вы собираетесь использовать СУБД только для хранения данных и вам не нужны всякие крутые фишки мощных СУБД, то MySql вам хватит. Но многое придется реализовывать в клиентском приложении, так как возможности MySql скудные и там нет, например, T-SQL.

**Почему тормозит?**

Тут может быть несколько вариантов:

1. Слабое железо. Для БД нужно иметь мощный ПК.
2. Плохая архитектура БД.
3. Отсутствуют индексы на полях, которые участвуют в связях.
4. Access... Все таки эта программа предназначена в первую очередь для работы с базами Access, а не MySql...

Comment: Да.. Некорректно выразился.. По диспетчеру задач смотрел... С компом всё нормально... Тормозит Аксес.. Комп: 2,6Ггц, ОЗУ-6,0Гб. Win7.  "Ты его используешь как оболочку для отчетов, а все вытягиваешь из MySql?" - объём базы более 2,0Гб Аксес с таким объёмом не работает. MySql вроде тянет. Предполагаю базу разместить в MySql,а Аксес как интерфейс: корректировка данных, в некоторых полях форматирование некоторых фрагментов текста (жирный, цвет, заливка).. PS пока осваиваю, поэтому прошу делать поправку не корректность  вопросов и решений.  Ну и потом предполагается подключить пользователей из инт

Comment: @koverflow, я не уверен, но Access при выполнении запросов кеширует данные. Например, имеется 2 Access базы, где есть таблицы весом по 1,5 гб. Так вот, если 1 аксесс линкануть в другой и сделать UNION, то БД Access поломается. Я бы на твоем месте поискал бы Альтернативу Access. Все таки он в первую очередь для работы с Access БД.

Comment: @koverflow, и вообще, вроде, ODBC- это универсальный драйвер=> может не оптимально работать. Если работать с MySql через правильную утилиту, то должен использоваться родной драйвер=> буст производительности.

Comment: "Я бы на твоем месте поискал бы Альтернативу Access" - Написать на C# программку для подключения к БД. И работать с БД через "dataGridView". Это решение или глупость? Если не хлопотно навскидку можете предложить свои решения или ссылки

Comment: "Если работать с MySql через правильную утилиту" - можете, что-нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: @koverflow,Я ссылку привел в ответе https://habrahabr.ru/post/142385/ .

Comment: @koverflow, написание своего решения имеет смысл, если вы не нашли подходящей утилиты, которая удволитворяет ваши потребности, в противном случае- это изобретение велосипеда.

Comment: Я пока использую "HeidiSQL"..  "Я бы на твоем месте поискал бы Альтернативу Access" - Написать на C# программку для подключения к БД. И работать с БД через "dataGridView". Это решение или глупость? Если не хлопотно навскидку можете предложить свои решения или ссылки.  Или вы имеете ввиду, что-то на подобие "HeidiSQL"?

Comment: @koverflow, ну например, вот такая штука есть http://www.dbschema.com/forms-and-reports.html . Тебе нужен инструмент, как я понимаю, который позволит, без знания запросов создавать новые записи?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53091/discussion-between-koverflow-and-iluxa1810).

Answer (score 1):

При таких объемах связывать локальную и серверную таблицы весьма невыгодно в плане производительности. Переместите все таблицы на сервер и используейте pass-trough запросы, это позволит максимально испозовать мощность серверной базы данных, а Акцесс в качестве фронтенда очень неплох.

Comment: Я правильно вас понял?  Разместил всё на сервере
Сделал форму на которой нужно ввести критерий запроса.
Сделал запрос "К серверу" 

SELECT tbl5.*, tbl5.idsub
FROM tbl5
WHERE (((tbl5.idsub)=[Формы]![03_frm_00_tbl_00]![03_frm_idsub]));

В результате выдаёт ошибку.
Как можно исправить ошибку?   http://prntscr.com/e59ias

Comment: Вместо [Формы]![03_frm_00_tbl_00]![03_frm_idsub] нужно подставлять конкретное значение, т.е. тест запроса меняется перед каждым обновлением формы